# 2-Dence neural network accuracy optimization

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras

Below you can see the dataset i use"sorted_output" in order to construct an ANN with 2 hidden dense layers and one input, one output layer. My question is why am i getting extremely low accuracy(62,5%)? I have the feeling that the fact that since both my input data (columns A-U) and my output data (column V) are in binary form, this should lead me to 100% accuracy. Am i wrong?

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import numpy

# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("sorted_output.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:21]
Y = dataset[:,21]
# split into 67% for train and 33% for test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=seed)
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=21, init='orthogonal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='orthogonal', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Features being binary values do not necessarily lead to good performance. It depends on how your data distribute.

Comment: can you provide relative literature?

Answer (score 0):

Accuracy of the network depends on many factors. It is really difficult to understand why the accuracy is so low in your case. It really depends on the underlying data distribution and how good you network is at capturing the relevant information during training.

I suggest you to monitor the loss and see if the model is overfitting the train data. If that is the case, you might have to use some kind of regularization to improve the generalization. Otherwise, you can increase the depth of the network and check if results are better.

These are by no means an exhaustive list of approaches. Sometimes changing the optimizer also helps, depending on how your data distributed.